# Why doesn't my program run correctly?

Tags: java, for-loop

for my school project I have to create a program that outputs perfect numbers based on how many perfect numbers the user(teacher) want. The user can pick any number from 1-4 and it should display however many number the user chooses. Here is my current code. Please ignore the sumupTo, factorial, isprime, and the testGoldbach methods, please only look at the Perfect numbers method/code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyMathB
{

  public static int sumUpTo(int n)
  {
int sum = 0;

for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
  sum += k;

return sum;
  }


  public static long factorial(int n)
  {
long f = 1;

for (int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
  f *= k;

return f;
  }

  public static boolean isPrime(int n)
  {
    if (n <= 1)
      return false;

int m = 2;

while (m * m <= n)
{
  if (n % m == 0)
return false;
  m++;
}

return true;
  }

  public static void PerfectNumbers(int number)
{
    System.out.println("How many perfect numbers would you like to see? Please enter an integer from 1 to 4");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numbersToSee = s.nextInt();
    int counts = 0;

    for(counts = 0; counts <= numbersToSee; counts++)
    {
        for (int n = 5; n <= 10000; n++)
        {
             int temp = 0;

             for(int i = 1; i <= number / 2; i++)
             {
                 if (number % i == 0)
                 {
                     temp += i;

                 }
                 if (temp == number)
                 {
                     System.out.println(number);
                 }

             }
        }


    }
}

  public static boolean testGoldbach(int bigNum)
  {
    for (int n = 6; n <= bigNum; n += 2)  
{
  boolean found2primes = false;

      for (int p = 3; p <= n/2; p += 2)
      {
    if (isPrime(p) && isPrime(n - p))
      found2primes = true;
  }

  if (!found2primes)
  {
System.out.println(n + " is not a sum of two primes!");
return false;
  }
}

return true;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;

do
{
  System.out.print("Enter an integer from 4 to 20: ");
  n = kb.nextInt();
} while (n < 4 || n > 20);

kb.close();

System.out.println();
System.out.println("1 + ... + " + n + " = " + sumUpTo(n));
System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial(n));
System.out.println("Primes: ");
for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
  if (isPrime(k))
System.out.print(k + " ");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Goldbach conjecture up to " + n + ": " + testGoldbach(n));
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, its "Why doesn't my program run correctly?"

Comment: Edit the title, don't add it as a comment. And tell us what happens and what's expected.

Comment: *"Please ignore the sumupTo, factorial, isprime, and the testGoldbach methods"* If those really are irrelevant to reproducing the problem behavior, then you should remove them from the example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Nothing calls `PerfectNumbers`. Could that be why the program doesn't display any perfect numbers?

Comment: I'm guessing it's displaying the same perfect number 'x' amount of times. That because you start the loop to check if a number is perfect from the start several times. That's an issue.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  Oops!  You're right.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declare the variable "number" in your method.

Edit: you didn't ***SET*** the variable number to anything, I misworded my last statement.

Comment: if you mean the `PerfectNumbers` method, `number` is a parameter; it will be set to whatever argument is passed when the method is called.  Only problem is: nothing ever calls it.